# What is the purpose of declaring final methods in final classes in Java

Tags: java, oop

I was reading LinkedHashMap source code and i came across with inner final class LinkedKeyIterator.Also i have seen lots of same code in java's source code.

Which is like that:

```
  final class LinkedKeyIterator extends LinkedHashIterator
        implements Iterator<K> {
        public final K next() { return nextNode().getKey(); }
    }
```

We know that final classes cant be extended so we can not override methods.

Why next method declared as final?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe it would help the JIT to inline the method, making the code run more efficiently.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The JIT should be able to inline the method regardless, since it is treated as though it's final.

Comment: One of possible reasons is that making class final doesn't mean that compiler will implicitly add `final` keyword to all methods. So if you would write tool which via reflection would search for all final methods based on `final` keyword in their signature, methods in final class wouldn't be found.

Comment: @Pshemo: Good point!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks

Comment: There is also a much simpler reason why it is done sometimes: the developer is unsure if really all methods will be final (so bad planning and/or bad specifications)

Comment: @maraca joshua bloch wrote that class so i don't think that there is a bad planning/specification

Comment: @neat159 I wasn't trying to imply that, your question seems pretty general, have to admit it's easier to just remove the final from the class and not having to add the final to most of the methods then if some would change.

Answer (score 4):

It's purely documentation/emphasis, per [JLS§8.4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3):

> A `private` method and all methods declared immediately within a `final` class (§8.1.1.2) behave as if they are `final`, since it is impossible to override them.

As [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035279/what-is-the-purpose-of-declaring-final-methods-in-final-classes-in-java#comment51971537_32035279), whether the method was *declared* `final` can be determined via reflection, and the compiler won't automatically add that to the signature. So making methods explicitly `final` improves documentation right down to the reflection level.